# The conversion of the varchar value '6000545901' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Begin
   UPDATE pmptxft 
   SET
    vaccno = (SELECT  max(cast(isnull(vaccno,0) AS int)) + 1 FROM pmptxft WHERE iPRACID=@IPRACID)
   WHERE ipatId = @PatientIdentity
  END
```

Here vaccno  datatype is varchar(max). Any Help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume a datatype error is the cause. When you compare two values of a different datatype an automatic datatype conversion can cause such an error.

Check the datatypes of

- the ipracis column and the @IPRACID variable
- the ipatId column and the @PatientIdentity variable

Answer (score 0):

The value `6000545901` is out of the range. The `int` data type has a [range of](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
```

Try using `BIGINT` instead:

```
UPDATE pmptxft 
SET    vaccno = (SELECT Max(Cast(Isnull(vaccno, 0) AS BIGINT)) + 1 
                 FROM   pmptxft 
                 WHERE  ipracid = @IPRACID) 
WHERE  ipatid = @PatientIdentity
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52233/5)'s a working example.